# update of spring data elasticsearch to 3.0.7

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, elasticsearch, java-8, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have update my spring data elasticsearch to version 3.0.7 
I wanna know if i should also update spring core version because after runnig my project an exception thrown

```html
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restParametrageCompetenceController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: ma.accolade.ged.ms.gestion.parametrage.service.CompetenceService ma.accolade.ged.ms.gestion.parametrage.controller.RestParametrageCompetenceController.competenceService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'CompetenceService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: ma.accolade.ged.ms.gestion.parametrage.persistance.CompetencePersistance ma.accolade.ged.ms.gestion.parametrage.service.impl.CompetenceImpl.competenceRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'competencePersistance': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
```

Comment: Can you provide previous version of spring-core and data? Can you also provide configuration, which cause this error?

Comment: spring-core : 4.2.0.RELEASE
spring-context : 4.2.0.RELEASE
spring-beans : 4.2.0.RELEASE
spring-data-elasticsearch  3.0.8.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

You should use the release-train dependency. This way everything is in sync.

http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/#quick-start

Comment: the same probleme again